# Object is possibly 'null' in Angular Form validation

Tags: angular

I am doing a validation on a form to check if a number input is greater than a certain number.
I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65966761/13419834), but I am still getting the same error.

But in am getting the following error:

```
error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
 <small style="color: red;" [hidden]="myForm.get('checkAmount').hasError?'maxlength'">
                                                                ~~~~~~~~

  src/app/withdraw/withdraw.component.ts:10:16
    10   templateUrl: './withdraw.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component WithdrawComponent.
```

Here is my code:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" class="space" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="amount" size="230" placeholder="Amount To Withdraw" 
    formControlName="checkAmount"
    [(ngModel)]="model.Balance"
    maxlength=50
    >
    <small style="color: red;" [hidden]="myForm.get('checkAmount').hasError?'maxlength'">
        The value should not exceed the balance
    </small>
</form>
```

Comment: `myForm?.get('checkAmount')?.hasError?.'maxlength'"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put the `?` operator to every chaining to be safe:

```html
[hidden]="myForm?.get('checkAmount')?.hasError('maxlength')"
```

Comment: It has compiled successfully, but it is displaying the <small> data even before I fill in the form.

Comment: Well before you fill the form you don't have the maxlength error, right? Hence, that evaluates to `false` and `hidden="false"` would indeed display the error. You can/should revert the condition or use an `*ngIf` instead of `[hidden]`

Comment: Before filling the form, it is already displaying "The value should not exceed the balance".  I will try the ```*ngIf```

Comment: How do I revert the condition?

Comment: `!(myForm?.get('checkAmount')?.hasError('maxlength'))`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[hidden]="myForm.get('checkAmount').errors?.maxlength"
```