# Not able to validate the form in angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h2>Registration Form</h2>
  <form [formGroup]="registrationForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

    {{registrationForm.value|json}}

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Username</label>
      <input [class.is-invalid]="registrationForm.get('userName').invalid && registrationForm.get('userName').touched"
             formControlName="userName" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input formControlName="password" type="password" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Confirm  Password</label>
      <input  formControlName="confirmPassword" type="password" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div formGroupName="address">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>City</label>
        <input  formControlName="city" type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>State</label>
        <input  formControlName="state" type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Postal Code</label>
        <input  formControlName="postalCode" type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!registrationForm.valid">Register</button>
    <button (click)="loadApiData()" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Load API Data</button>

  </form>

</div>
```

TS File

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-form2',
  templateUrl: './product-form2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-form2.component.css']
})
export class ProductForm2Component implements OnInit {

  registrationForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    // this.registrationForm = new FormGroup(
    //   {
    //     userName: new FormControl('Devesh'),
    //     password: new FormControl(''),
    //     confirmPassword: new FormControl(''),
    //     address: new FormGroup({
    //       city: new FormControl(''),
    //       state: new FormControl(''),
    //       postalCode: new FormControl('')
    //     })
    //
    //   }
    // )

    this.registrationForm = this.fb.group({
      userName: ['Devesh', Validators.required],
      password: [''],
      confirmPassword: [''],
      address:  this.fb.group({
        city: [''],
        state:[''],
        postalCode:['']
      })
    });

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit() {
    // TODO: Use EventEmitter with form value
    console.warn(this.registrationForm.value);
  }

  loadApiData(){
    this.registrationForm.setValue({
      userName: '',
      password: '123',
      confirmPassword: '123',
      address: {
        city: '123',
        state: '123',
        postalCode:'123'
      }


    })
  }

}
```

Without adding validation it work well, but with validation it gave this error:

```
Error: product-form2/product-form2.component.html:9:67 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

9       <input [class.is-invalid]="registrationForm.get('userName').invalid && registrationForm.get('userName').touched"
                                                                ~~~~~~~

  product-form2/product-form2.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './product-form2.component.html',

Error occurs in the template of component ProductForm2Component.


Error: product-form2/product-form2.component.html:9:111 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

9       <input [class.is-invalid]="registrationForm.get('userName').invalid && registrationForm.get('userName').touched"
                                                                                                                ~~~~~~~

  product-form2/product-form2.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './product-form2.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component ProductForm2Component.
```

what can be wrong? FYI, I am using angular using angular 12.

Comment: try to use registrationForm?.get('userName').invalid

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object is possibly 'null' in Angular Form validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67654596/object-is-possibly-null-in-angular-form-validation)

Comment: @SantoshAnand This does not solve the error.

Comment: it got fixed after adding ? after get('userName')

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `registrationForm.controls`;

In your HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h2>Registration Form</h2>
  <form [formGroup]="registrationForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

    {{registrationForm.value|json}}

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Username</label>
     
      <input [class.is-invalid]="registrationForm.controls.userName.invalid && registrationForm.controls.userName.touched"
             formControlName="userName" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input formControlName="password" type="password" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Confirm  Password</label>
      <input  formControlName="confirmPassword" type="password" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div formGroupName="address">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>City</label>
        <input  formControlName="city" type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>State</label>
        <input  formControlName="state" type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Postal Code</label>
        <input  formControlName="postalCode" type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!registrationForm.valid">Register</button>
    <button (click)="loadApiData()" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Load API Data</button>

  </form>

</div>
```

TS file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-form2',
  templateUrl: './product-form2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-form2.component.css']
})
export class ProductForm2Component implements OnInit {

  registrationForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.registrationForm = this.fb.group({
      userName: ['Devesh', Validators.required],
      password: [''],
      confirmPassword: [''],
      address:  this.fb.group({
        city: [''],
        state:[''],
        postalCode:['']
      })
    });

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit() {
    // TODO: Use EventEmitter with form value
    console.warn(this.registrationForm.value);
  }

  loadApiData(){
    this.registrationForm.setValue({
      userName: '',
      password: '123',
      confirmPassword: '123',
      address: {
        city: '123',
        state: '123',
        postalCode:'123'
      }


    })
  }

}
```

Here is a demo of your code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbqydf?file=src/app/dialog-content-example.html)

Comment: you can use `registrationForm.controls.userName.errors?.required`too.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h2>Registration Form</h2>
  {{registrationForm.value | json}}
  <form [formGroup]="registrationForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Username</label>
      <input [class.is-invalid]="registrationForm.get('userName')?.invalid && registrationForm.get('userName')?.touched " formControlName="userName" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input formControlName="password" type="password" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Confirm Password</label>
      <input formControlName="confirmPassword" type="password" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div formGroupName="address">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>City</label>
        <input formControlName="city" type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>State</label>
        <input formControlName="state" type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Postal Code</label>
        <input formControlName="postalCode" type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
    <button (click)="loadAPI()" class="btn btn-primary ml-5" type="button">Load API Data</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer might solve the problem, but it’s hard to know why!  Please edit your answer to explain what you changed and why.

Answer (score -1):

I think your registrationForm object is not initialized at that moment.

Try adding a condition for null check of registrationForm as well.

```
  <input [class.is-invalid]="**registrationForm** && registrationForm.get('userName').invalid && registrationForm.get('userName').touched"
/>
```

or put your whole form inside a if container

```
<ng-container *ngIf="registrationForm">
<!-- your form -->
</ng-container>
```

Comment: with that change also i am getting same error.

Comment: This condition is always true and did not apply the error @DeveshAgrawal has.

Answer (score -1):

From angular https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#validating-input-in-reactive-forms

You can define getters for the properties like so

```
get name() { return this.heroForm.get('name'); }

get power() { return this.heroForm.get('power'); }
```

Then you can edit your html to have this :

```
[class.is-invalid]="userName.invalid && userName.touched"
```

That will get rid of your 'is possibly null' error

another way is to add the following helper to your .ts file

```
  get f() {
    return this.issueForm.controls;
  }
```

then your html code can be re-written like so :

```
[class.is-invalid]="this.f.userName.invalid && this.f.userName.touched"
```